# KML file - Extract Description values from HTML tags

Tags: php, kml

I am trying to extract a specific value from a KML file I was given.

The description tag of the file looks like:

```
<description>&lt;h4&gt;population_data_per_block&lt;/h4&gt;

&lt;ul class="textattributes"&gt;

&lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span class="atr-name"&gt;gid&lt;/span&gt;:&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;span class="atr-value"&gt;745&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span class="atr-name"&gt;ESYE_CODE&lt;/span&gt;:&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;span class="atr-value"&gt;546&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span class="atr-name"&gt;Population&lt;/span&gt;:&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;span class="atr-value"&gt;331&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
</description>
```

I am only interested in the Population line of the description and its atr-value.

with a simple explode I was able to extract the values inside the description field

```
  $desc_bits = explode('</tr>', $place->description);
```

My would like something that could parse each line and if "Population" is found, keep its value

EDIT:

```
  print_r($hello = trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($desc_bits[0]))));
```

Outputs:

```
population_data_per_block gid: 2725 ESYE_CODE: 2377 Population: 81
```

Comment: i'd suggest use `DOMDocument` for this task instead of using string manipulation functions

Comment: In case it's helpful, there is a QGIS plugin called "KML Tools" which includes the ability to parse the name/value pairs out of the HTML in KML balloons. You could bring your KML into QGIS, expand the balloon contents into an attribute table, and export that as a CSV or other tabular format.